# 302 Found on Laravel in GET request made by cross-fetch on react

Tags: laravel, reactjs, react-redux, fetch, http-status-code-302

I have a component with a table, when this component mounts I would like to make a request to get data that fills the table.

In my table component:

```
 componentDidMount() {
    const { fetchTransactions } = this.props;
    fetchTransactions()
  }
```

This came from (I'm using redux):

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    fetchTransactions: value => dispatch(fetchTransactions())
})
```

And the action:

```
export function fetchTransactions() {
  return function (dispatch) {
    dispatch(requestTransactions())
    return fetch('/getTransactions')
    .then(
      response => response.json(),
      error => console.log('An error occurred.', error)
    )
    .then(json => dispatch(receiveTransactions(json)))
  }
}
```

When the component mounts, the action is dispatched and the fetch too, but the response is a 302 found as you can see here:
[image]

Using the browser it work as I expect:

[image]

Any ideas? thank you.

Comment: Please add the full 302 response to your question.

Comment: Hi @TarekAdam, the response headers?